# Insert query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Here is the custom UDT I created in cassandra, But I'm not able to frame correct insert query for the UDT.

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS three (
    a text,
    b text
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS two (
    c text,
    d frozen < list< frozen < three > >  >
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS one (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    main frozen < two >
);

the following insert query is giving column type incompatible error in datastax dev center`insert into one (id, main) values ('something', 
    [
        {
        'c' : 'something',
        'three': [{'a':'something', 'b': 'something'}]
        }
]);`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
insert into one (id, main) values ('something', {       
    c : 'something',
    d : [ {a:'something', b: 'something'}]
    }
);
```

You have gone wrong at multiple places.

1. definition of `one` doesn't have a list.
2. definition of `two` contains c,d - not c, three.
3. Please use `c` or `"c"` instead of `'c'`

I hope you try more before you post it on stack-overflow.